# How to delete row at dynamic tableView Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Here is my problem. I have a users array, and im checking if user phone number is in address book i want to show user in tableView.

```
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return users.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! UserCell

    let user = users[indexPath.row]
    let contact = searchForContactUsingPhoneNumber(phoneNumber: user.phoneNumber!)
    if contact == true {
        cell.textLabel?.text = user.name
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = user.phoneNumber
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(r: 35, g: 35, b: 35)
        cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.white
        cell.detailTextLabel?.textColor = UIColor.white

        if let profileImageUrl = user.profileImageUrl {
        cell.profileImageView.loadImageUsingCacheWithUrlString(profileImageUrl)

        } else {
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
            tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
    return cell
}
```

Here is what i have. Its deleting a user row if phone number is NOT in address book but it leaves white row instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't modify the number of cells in the table, or reload the tableview, in your cellForRowAt. It's better to filter the users array first and use the resulting, filtered array as the data source instead.

Sort of like

```
let usersWithPhoneNumbers = users.filter { $0.profileImageUrl != nil && searchForContactUsingPhoneNumber(phoneNumber: $0.phoneNumber!) }
```

and then use the usersWithPhoneNumbers array in your numberOfRows and cellForRow methods instead.

Comment: Agreed, deleting rows that are not supposed to be shown at all in the first place is not a great way to filter the list. Do it beforehand, use the filtered list as the 1:1 datasource.